# prevent unix.multiselect auto sorting on selected items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery.uix.multiselect by yanickrochon, API documentation here:
[API Documentation](https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect/wiki/API-Documentation)

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">
   <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
   <option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
   <option value="AND">Andorra</option>
   <option value="ARG">Argentina</option>
   <option value="ARM">Armenia</option>
   <option value="ABW">Aruba</option>
   <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
   <option value="AZE">Azerbaijan</option>
   <option value="BGD">Bangladesh</option>
   <option value="BLR">Belarus</option>
   <option value="BEL">Belgium</option>
</select>
```

And JS:

```
$(".multiselect").multiselect(
    {availableListPosition:'left', sortable: true }
);
```

When I select a country, it goes to the selected panel sorted, I enabled `sortable` so I can drag and sort manually. My question is: is there a way to append the newly selected country to the bottom of the selected list? instead of automatically sorted along with the selected list. 
The one option I see `sortMethod` can disable the sorting, but would like the un-selected list to be sorted for easy find. Does anyone with experience with this?
In sort, I am looking to keep the un-selected list sorted while items in the selected list is appended to the bottom.